# Updating TSQL Column From a JSON_VALUE in Another Table?

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql

I have a database with two tables in it, one of which contains some information about a user who accessed a website, and the other containing a foreign key to the first table and a pile of JSON data about their request.

There's a problem with double-hops where it's recording the service account that made the request rather than the user name; since this `UserName` is recorded in the `ModelData` column of the other table, I'd like to correct these service accounts.

Here is what I've tried:

```
UPDATE Table_A
SET Table_A.CreatedBy = JSON_VALUE(Table_B.ModelData,'$.Action.UserName')
FROM Table_A
INNER JOIN Table_B ON (Table_B.Table_AID = Table_A.ID)
WHERE CreatedBy LIKE '%svc.%'
```

What I thought it would do:

1. Where the `CreatedBy` column is currently equal to a "svc" account,
2. Find the matching `ModelData` from the other table,
3. Pull the `UserName` from the JSON string, and
4. Assign it to `CreatedBy`.

What it actually does is throw this error:

> JSON text is not properly formatted. Unexpected character '.' is found at position 0

Comment: Does `select count(*) from Table_B where ISJSON(ModelData) = 0` return anything?

Comment: You have a problem with the data on `Table_B.ModelData` in at least one record that fits the conditions of the query.

Comment: @LukStorms Yes, it returned "8". I have been working on the assumption that if there was no '$.Action.UserName' or no JSON at all it would just skip the row, is that not the case?

Comment: @ErikL It means that there are 8 records that contain a string that's not a valid JSON. Hence that "not properly formatted" error. If it's valid, but there's no '$.Action.UserName' then I assume the CreatedBy will just be updated to NULL (haven't tested it). You could correct those invalid json's, Or add a `AND ISJSON(Table_B.ModelData) = 1` to your update query to avoid them.

Comment: @LukStorms Thanks, you definitely got me on the right track with your two comments. I've done a SET ... = IIF(ISJSON(...)) with a IsNull(...) check inside of it, and now it's working perfectly. Thanks again!

Comment: @ErikL Cool, glad it works.  Post it as an answer and I'll upvote. I was about to suggest a COALESCE, but ISNULL works also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LukStorms pointed out the problem in my assumptions; if the field was empty *or* there was no UserName to be found, the script would fail. Doing a couple of checks fixed this.

```sql
UPDATE Table_A
SET Table_A.CreatedBy = IIF(IsJson(Table_B.ModelData) > 0,
    IsNull(JSON_VALUE(Table_B.ModelData,'$.Action.UserName'), Table_A.CreatedBy),
    Table_A.CreatedBy)
FROM Table_A
INNER JOIN Table_B ON (Table_B.Table_AID = Table_A.ID)
WHERE CreatedBy LIKE '%svc.%'
```

First we need to make sure that the content of `ModelData` is actually a JSON string as opposed to normal text or blank space, than we also need to make sure the actual JSON value of `$.Action.UserName` isn't null. Once that's been done we can safely write the value.